# Removing or blocking default Android apps

Tags: applications, uninstallation, task-management

I have developed a software for a company, not for a personal use, and I need to block some app access on Android.

I need to block the user from making calls, sending sms, using the Android Market, using Gmail and several other apps.

As I see it there are two options:

1 - Uninstalling default apps with "Titanium Backup" and If need to use this device to do calls again I will reinstall the original ROM or restore a Titanium Backup.

2 - Use a software with a ignore list and this software will kill all the ignored process(Backgronud, Foreground), and this software needs to use a adminitrator password for configuration.

So does this software exists? Uninstalling is a good option? Are there other options?

Comment: Do you trust your user will not try to circumvent your blocking? In the end of the day, any protection is futile; user can always reflash their phone with a custom ROM. There is no way to provide true blocking unless you used custom hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling via Titanium will work for removing Gmail, Market and Messaging, but be very careful removing Phone.apk, as it's tightly integrated into core services.  You might start seeing Force Closes and other instability from the handset.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you need to roll your own version of the OS.

Comment: And get a vendor to sell you a certificate and devices with a bootloader that looks for that.  Or just give up and accept that someone will always be able to re-purpose hardware put into their physical possession.

Answer (score 1):

If you merely wish to prevent a user from accessing certain applications use an app that allows you to password protect and thereby prevent a user from using said app.

You can then protect the Phone, Email, Market app etc.

Note however, that a resourceful user can always sideload alternative apps via the SD card or the browser (if that isn't protected too) and use it thusly.

There are [lots](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) [of](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ruimaninfo.approtect) [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.carrotapp.protectpronew) protection apps in the market

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to block these features permanently, or only while your app is running?  If you want it permanent, why not issue a non-phone android device?  In addition the media devices generally don't come with any google apps installed.